# java storing integer input from files to array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, java.util.scanner

Consider that I have a file with some numbers as below - the name of the file is
seminar.txt. This file is a data set that I collected on the number of students who
attended my seminar sessions in the months of January - March. Some of these data is
text. Your task is to extract only the number of students and calculate and display the
total number of students who attended the seminars in the three months. Call this
program Seminar.java

```
January
Week 1 23
Week 2 30
Week 3 20
Week 4 40
February
Week 1 20
Week 2 19
Week 3 19
Week 4 20
March
Week 1 10
Week 2 50
Week 3 21
Week 4 20
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  You need to show some effort, and ask a question which will help you learn how to do this for yourself.

Comment: It's like he's giving us a request, `Your task is...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.satya.prakash.service.impl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Seminar {

    static String filePath = "D:\\seminar.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(filePath);

        if (f.exists()) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

            String str;
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(str);
            }
            String strArray[] = text.toString().replace("January", "").replace("February","").replace("March", "").replace("Week","").trim().split(" ");

            boolean flag=false;
            Integer sum=0;
            for(String s :strArray) {
                if(flag) {
                    try {
                        sum= sum + Integer.parseInt(s);
                    }catch(Exception e) {}
                    flag=false;
                }else
                    flag=true;
            }
            System.out.println("Total Number of Student : "+sum);

        } else
            System.out.println("File Not Found...");

    }

}

Output : Total Number of Student : 129
```

Comment: here is what i was trying

Comment: public static int[] readFiles(String file){
    
       try {
           
           File f = new File(file);
           Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
           int ctr = 0;
           
           while(s.hasNextInt()) {
           
           ctr++;
           s.next();
           
           }
        int[] arr = new int[ctr];
        
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(f);
        
        for(int i=0;i< arr.length;i++){
        
        arr[i] = s1.nextInt();
        
        return arr;
        }
       catch(exception e){
        return null;
        }
       }}

Comment: s.hasNextInt() - will false when next item is not a string value... but in your input its a alphanumeric white space and number all things